# npm for react installation is not accepted for my windows

Tags: reactjs

Could you please help me with[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhBNT.png) React installation, npm is not accepted, it says 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Please see the picture attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you haven't installed Node.js. Try installing Node.js from here: https://nodejs.org/en/